# Finding Lengths With Recursion (Without Dijkstra)

Tags: java, recursion

Simply because this is an exercise to practice recursion, my professor gave the code to find the coordinates of all solutions in a maze.  This makes sense, and I added all these solutions to an `ArrayList solutions` I now want to create a `for` loop outside the recursion, and go through the list, and find the smallest length of the coordinates, and update accordingly like you would finding the smallest `integer` of an `ArrayList`.

But, it's adding empty `ArrayList<Coord>s`, to `ArrayList solutions`, so, when I try to get the first element, it's comparing with empty elements, so it's not finding the shortest length. Does anyone know how to just get the solutions, and add them to my `ArrayList`??

This is the recursive code given to me:

```
 else{     
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Coord>> solutions = new ArrayList<Array List<Coord>>();
    for(int i=0; i<directions.length; i++){ 
    Coord nextSpot = currentSpot.addTo(directions[i]);e
    if(nextSpot.validSpot(maze)) 
      if(!newPath.contains(nextSpot)){ 

        ArrayList<Coord> solution = //The recursive call
                         solve(newPath,nextSpot,goal,maze);
        if(solution != null)
        {
          solutions.add(solution);

        }

    }//ifs
  }//for
```

This is where I attempt to find the smallest path:

```
  ArrayList<Coord> smallestPath = (ArrayList<Coord>)solutions.get(0);
  ArrayList currentPath = new ArrayList();

  for(int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i++){
    currentPath = (ArrayList)solutions.get(i);
    if(currentPath.size() < smallestPath.size()){
      smallestPath = currentPath;
    }
    System.out.println("currentPath is : " + currentPath);
  }
   return smallestPath;

}//else (recursive case)
```